# Angular2 / NPM / VS2015 - Where is my 'bundles' folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, npm, angular

Every tutorial references /node_modules/angular2/bundles/...

Why don't I have the 'bundles' folders? For angular, or any library I get from NPM in Visual Studio 2015?

Pulled down from NPM

```
 "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.15",
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use npm and yeoman to scaffold your application.
Here is the complete article on github:
https://github.com/albatrosary/generator-angular2-eggs